# Use RouterLink from a nested component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using Angular 2 beta.0

I have a component structure like so

```
App (Has RouteConfig)
 -> List 
 | -> ListItem (Want to use RouterLink from here)
```

This results in an error: `Component "List" has no route config.`

So I put a RouteConfig on the `List` component like so...

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/:id', name: 'Details', component: Detail}
])
```

But I get an error in angular like `Error: Child routes are not allowed for "/list". Use "..." on the parent's route path.`

I have tried adding these 3 dots before and after the /list path in that route config... with no success.

The documentation on router is very light and though I know this is supposed to be based off of ui-router, I'm not seeing the parallel to add nested routes

Comment: That depends on how are you using your routerLink. Say for example you want to go from `ListItem` to `App` (the only two with RouteConfig), so you specify `routerLink="['/SomeRouteInApp']"` (note the `/`, that makes it absolute, you're going up!). if you want to go keep it relative to the component where you are you specify the routerLink with `./` or with no slash at all. If you post your routerLink it will be easier to see, and a repro would be even better (sorry for the long comment).

Answer (score 20):

You can use it like this, in parent component:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
  {path: '/list/...', component: ListComponent, as: 'List'}
])
```

And then in your `ListComponent`, define your child routes:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/:id', component: ListItem, as: 'ListItem' }
])
```

Make sure the `ListComponent` has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as well..

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is to use the *routerLink* from one child component to actually go to one of your parent's configured routes, then you don't need to put any *RouterConfig* on the child, you just need to make sure that the route is configured correctly in your parent and then add the *ROUTER_DIRECTIVES* constant in your child's directives property inside the child's decorator.

It will be something like this:

**Parent:**

```
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
        :
    (some more imports)
        :
@Component({
        :
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
        :
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/:id', name: 'Details', component: Detail}
])
```

**Child:**

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
    :
    :
@Component({
    :
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    :
})
```

Also, don't forget to configure your *routerLink* correctly by providing the route you want to send the user to as the first parameter of the array and then add the parameters you want to send to the target route by using the same name you gave them in the *RouteConfig*, like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['Details', { id: product.productId }]"> Details link </a>
```