# Deep Linking in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am pretty new to Angular2. Is there a way to do deep linking in Angular2 to say...something like this http://may-app.com/projects/1/files/2?

I can do http://my-app.com/projects/1 with the provided routing and routing parameters in Angular2 with this code

```
onClick(project){
  this.router.navigate(['/projects', project.id ]);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It really isn't at all clear what you're asking. Yes, you can do deep linking, just use the router. What is is about the routing that you don't understand? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The code I pasted above navigates to http://localhost:4200/projects/1. What I wanted is to navigate to http://localhost:4200/projects/1/files/1. file data is also contained in the projects array of data.

Comment: this is possible only if you establish parent-child route relationship ie., `/file` is parent and `/1` is child to that view. As per my knowledge you can't.

Comment: How can I do that? @Nirus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363176/use-routerlink-from-a-nested-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding router children.

```
{ path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetails,
    children: [          
      { path: 'file/:fileid', component: Overview }

    ]
  }
```

To read more about deep linking i recommend to read this

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html